# What can slow down SupportMapFragment after adding Marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have problem with **SupportMapFragment** and speed after return **from another fragment** where I add some Markers to it.

My flow is : **MapFragment** -> **AddingFragment** -> **AddToStaticObjectOfMarker** -> **MapFragment** (where a clean map and repaint all Marker from StaticObjectOfMarker) - after this flow the map is very slow and almost impossible to move on it.

I was thinking about some power-wasting bug but the interesting part is that if I **lock** and **unlock** phone everything is fine. I was looking on onResume ( and almost whole lifecycle but doesnt find anything strange).

**Is there some Android mechanism which is triggered after lock/unlock operation which can be related with my problem ?**

I don't post my code because there are a plenty of unrelated code - but if someone need to check some part I will post it here.

**EDIT**
How I change fragment:

```
public void changeFragment(String toFragment, Bundle args){

    Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected");

    Fragment mCurrentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id

            .fragment_place);

    if(mCurrentFragment.getClass().getName() == toFragment){

        return;

    }

    Util.hideSoftKeyboard(this);

    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(toFragment);

    if(fragment == null){

        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,toFragment);

        if(args != null){

            fragment.setArguments(args);

        }

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

                .setCustomAnimations(

                        R.animator.fragment_slide_in, R.animator.fragment_slide_out, 0, 0)

                .replace(R.id.fragment_place,fragment)

                .addToBackStack(null)

                .commit();

    }else{

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

                .setCustomAnimations(

                        R.animator.fragment_slide_in, R.animator.fragment_slide_out, 0, 0)

                .replace(R.id.fragment_place,fragment)

                .addToBackStack(null)

                .commit();

    }

}
```

and in map fragment

```
private static View cachedView;

...

@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d(TAG, "cachedView is null == " + (cachedView == null));

    if (cachedView == null) {

        cachedView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) mContainingActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");

    ButterKnife.bind(this, cachedView);



    mLocationHelper.registerListener(this);



    return cachedView;

}
```

but there are some service to updating map - it is complex and I don't want to post it whole somewhere but if u want help I can provide you access to my git repository to look at whole code.

EDIT2:
I look at output of console and get these two interesting lines :

```
 09-29 12:31:59.154    7286-7301/cz.united121.android.revizori W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 12.205ms
 09-29 12:31:59.207    7286-7306/cz.united121.android.revizori I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 121977(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 47(2MB) LOS objects, 20% free, 21MB/27MB, paused 5.140ms total 91.364ms
```

after **lock android suspend all thread ?**

EDIT3:

I started use [Leak Canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) and after playing with my app a get this leak :

```
10-02 09:55:54.157 4383-9459/cz.united121.android.revizori D/LeakCanary: * cz.united121.android.revizori.activity.MapActivity has leaked:
10-02 09:55:54.157 4383-9459/cz.united121.android.revizori D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT thread com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.bg.f (named 'RenderDrive')
10-02 09:55:54.157 4383-9459/cz.united121.android.revizori D/LeakCanary: * references com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.bf.k
10-02 09:55:54.157 4383-9459/cz.united121.android.revizori D/LeakCanary: * references com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.mParent
10-02 09:55:54.157 4383-9459/cz.united121.android.revizori D/LeakCanary: * references android.widget.FrameLayout.mParent
10-02 09:55:54.157 4383-9459/cz.united121.android.revizori D/LeakCanary: * references android.widget.FrameLayout.mContext
10-02 09:55:54.157 4383-9459/cz.united121.android.revizori D/LeakCanary: * leaks cz.united121.android.revizori.activity.MapActivity instance
10-02 09:55:54.157 4383-9459/cz.united121.android.revizori D/LeakCanary: * Reference Key: 85e89bca-05f0-4d7a-8982-422e138b2e15
10-02 09:55:54.157 4383-9459/cz.united121.android.revizori D/LeakCanary: * Device: motorola motorola XT1032 falcon_tescogbsl
10-02 09:55:54.157 4383-9459/cz.united121.android.revizori D/LeakCanary: * Android Version: 5.0.2 API: 21 LeakCanary: 1.3.1
```

I tried **replace every context to applicationContext** to avoid reference to activityContext but i doesnt help - any idea what can cause this ?

Comment: better to show code, without code its hard to find

Comment: How many markers do you have?

Comment: @MarkPazon unfortunatelly about ten (maximum  for now)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am using GIT and I tracked problem between two commits and find a problem - I am using **ButterKnife** to bind my view and the problem was that I try to use **DialogFragment** and **bind** view in **onCreateView** but I forget **unbind** in **onDestroyView** ... very stupid ... but I dont know that binding (and maybe blocking garbage collector is so big problem)

Does anybody know why was that happening ?

Comment: But after some time it seems that solve problem only partly ... but I suppose that other slowing is causing by similar problem.